# grep buffer for previously executed command output

Tags: shell, grep, vxworks

Is it possible to grep the buffer?  For instance if I execute a build process in my VxWorks shell, linux shell, etc, is there a rolling file that contains buffer (e.g. data while scrolling)/previous output?

Comment: See also: [How to search terminal output](https://superuser.com/questions/304223/how-to-search-terminal-output)

Answer (score 0):

Use tee command:

```
building_command | tee -a rolling.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of tee - however I forgot to tee my output and would rather not rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to grep the buffer, but some terminal emulators have a function to search in the buffer.

In most terminal emulators you can select the text and then paste it into an editor and save it to a file, which you can grep.